# probability of purchasing an item based on past purchases

Tags: r, probability

I have some data on individual purchases.

In this data `PANID` is a person who bought a product on a particular week. In the sample I provide, there are 6 unique `PANID`'s; so 6 people in total. I am trying to calculate the conditional probability that a `PANID` will repurchase a product a second time.

For example:

`PANID` 3104497 bought `ITEM` 7028 in `WEEK` 2010-01-11 and then again the same `PANID` bought the same `ITEM` in `WEEK` 2010-01-25. I am trying to figure out how to find the probability that they will buy that same item again (at any point in the data).

```
    PANID       WEEK ITEM
1 3104497 2010-01-11  526
2 3104497 2010-01-11  526
3 3104497 2010-01-11  526
4 3104497 2010-01-11  526
5 3104497 2010-01-11  526
6 3104497 2010-01-11 2890
...
705 3146217 2010-04-05   97
706 3146217 2010-04-05  132
707 3146217 2010-04-05  132
708 3146217 2010-04-05  132
709 3146217 2010-04-05  132
710 3146217 2010-04-05  132
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(PANID = c(3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 
3369710L, 3369710L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 
3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 
3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 3369710L, 
3369710L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 
3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3138990L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 3104497L, 
3104497L, 3104497L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 
3816413L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 
3816413L, 3816413L, 3816413L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 3322156L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 
3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L, 3146217L), 
    WEEK = structure(c(14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 14620, 
    14620, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 
    14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14627, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 14634, 
    14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 
    14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 
    14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 
    14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 
    14641, 14641, 14641, 14641, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 
    14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 
    14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 
    14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 
    14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14648, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 
    14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 
    14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 
    14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 
    14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 
    14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 14669, 
    14669, 14669, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 
    14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 
    14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 
    14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 
    14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 
    14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 
    14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 
    14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14676, 14683, 14683, 14683, 
    14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 
    14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 
    14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 
    14683, 14683, 14683, 14683, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 
    14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 
    14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 
    14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14690, 14697, 
    14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 
    14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 
    14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 
    14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 
    14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14697, 14704, 14704, 14704, 
    14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 
    14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 
    14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 
    14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 
    14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 
    14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 14704, 
    14704, 14704), class = "Date"), ITEM = c(526L, 526L, 526L, 
    526L, 526L, 2890L, 2890L, 2890L, 2890L, 2890L, 2933L, 2933L, 
    2933L, 2933L, 2933L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 548L, 106L, 
    106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 6320L, 6320L, 6320L, 6320L, 6610L, 
    6610L, 6610L, 6610L, 7028L, 7028L, 7028L, 7028L, 7028L, 7414L, 
    7414L, 7414L, 7414L, 7414L, 1279L, 1279L, 1279L, 1279L, 1279L, 
    1425L, 1425L, 1425L, 1425L, 1425L, 6080L, 6080L, 6080L, 6080L, 
    1937L, 1937L, 1937L, 1937L, 1937L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11321L, 
    11321L, 11321L, 11321L, 12064L, 12064L, 12064L, 12064L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3448L, 3448L, 3448L, 3448L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 
    900L, 900L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 7363L, 7363L, 7363L, 
    7363L, 7362L, 7362L, 7362L, 7362L, 5995L, 5995L, 5995L, 5995L, 
    1251L, 1251L, 1251L, 1251L, 1251L, 76243L, 76243L, 76243L, 
    76243L, 76243L, 620L, 620L, 620L, 620L, 620L, 625L, 625L, 
    625L, 625L, 625L, 668L, 668L, 668L, 668L, 668L, 626L, 626L, 
    626L, 626L, 626L, 14772L, 14772L, 14772L, 14772L, 14772L, 
    27526L, 27526L, 27526L, 27526L, 27526L, 6320L, 6320L, 6320L, 
    6320L, 6500L, 6500L, 6500L, 6500L, 6560L, 6560L, 6560L, 6560L, 
    6610L, 6610L, 6610L, 6610L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 13902L, 
    13902L, 13902L, 13902L, 822L, 822L, 822L, 822L, 822L, 2178L, 
    2178L, 2178L, 2178L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 
    900L, 900L, 900L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 35202L, 35202L, 
    35202L, 35202L, 540L, 540L, 540L, 540L, 540L, 540L, 540L, 
    540L, 540L, 540L, 7363L, 7363L, 7363L, 7363L, 8312L, 8312L, 
    8312L, 8312L, 7362L, 7362L, 7362L, 7362L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 1251L, 1251L, 1251L, 1251L, 40268L, 40268L, 40268L, 
    40268L, 26037L, 26037L, 26037L, 26037L, 26037L, 26037L, 26037L, 
    26037L, 26037L, 4116L, 4116L, 4116L, 4116L, 4116L, 7789L, 
    7789L, 7789L, 7789L, 7028L, 7028L, 7028L, 7028L, 7028L, 1302L, 
    1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 13301L, 13301L, 13301L, 13301L, 240L, 
    240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 24444L, 24444L, 24444L, 24444L, 900L, 
    900L, 900L, 900L, 960L, 960L, 960L, 960L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 
    2202L, 38249L, 38249L, 38249L, 38249L, 28350L, 28350L, 28350L, 
    28350L, 28350L, 8358L, 8358L, 8358L, 8358L, 8358L, 5995L, 
    5995L, 5995L, 5995L, 40224L, 40224L, 40224L, 40224L, 40230L, 
    40230L, 40230L, 40230L, 40267L, 40267L, 40267L, 40267L, 40268L, 
    40268L, 40268L, 40268L, 42238L, 42238L, 42238L, 42238L, 42238L, 
    42274L, 42274L, 42274L, 42274L, 42274L, 42274L, 42274L, 42274L, 
    42274L, 42274L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
    95L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 1278L, 
    1278L, 1278L, 1278L, 1278L, 1278L, 1278L, 1278L, 1278L, 1278L, 
    6346L, 6346L, 6346L, 6346L, 6346L, 6346L, 6346L, 6346L, 6346L, 
    6346L, 81014L, 81014L, 81014L, 81014L, 81014L, 15990L, 15990L, 
    15990L, 15990L, 15990L, 8321L, 8321L, 8321L, 8321L, 8321L, 
    8321L, 8321L, 8321L, 8321L, 8321L, 27509L, 27509L, 27509L, 
    27509L, 27512L, 27512L, 27512L, 27512L, 27551L, 27551L, 27551L, 
    27551L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 960L, 960L, 960L, 960L, 
    2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 1111L, 1111L, 1111L, 1111L, 1081L, 
    1081L, 1081L, 1081L, 29422L, 29422L, 29422L, 29422L, 13830L, 
    13830L, 13830L, 13830L, 6080L, 6080L, 6080L, 6080L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 3637L, 3637L, 3637L, 3637L, 
    2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 7357L, 7357L, 7357L, 7357L, 7357L, 
    7363L, 7363L, 7363L, 7363L, 7363L, 85121L, 85121L, 85121L, 
    85121L, 40268L, 40268L, 40268L, 40268L, 42238L, 42238L, 42238L, 
    42238L, 96166L, 96166L, 96166L, 96166L, 96166L, 80997L, 80997L, 
    80997L, 80997L, 80997L, 2891L, 2891L, 2891L, 2891L, 2891L, 
    5169L, 5169L, 5169L, 5169L, 5169L, 27536L, 27536L, 27536L, 
    27536L, 27536L, 6150L, 6150L, 6150L, 6150L, 6150L, 31846L, 
    31846L, 31846L, 31846L, 31846L, 42753L, 42753L, 42753L, 42753L, 
    42753L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 2663L, 2663L, 2663L, 
    2663L, 2663L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 
    900L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 18285L, 18285L, 
    18285L, 18285L, 52531L, 52531L, 52531L, 52531L, 52531L, 7152L, 
    7152L, 7152L, 7152L, 1279L, 1279L, 1279L, 1279L, 1279L, 1425L, 
    1425L, 1425L, 1425L, 1425L, 13830L, 13830L, 13830L, 13830L, 
    6080L, 6080L, 6080L, 6080L, 3637L, 3637L, 3637L, 3637L, 2202L, 
    2202L, 2202L, 2202L, 26134L, 26134L, 26134L, 26134L, 600L, 
    600L, 600L, 600L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1302L, 1327L, 1327L, 
    1327L, 1327L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 
    900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 96166L, 96166L, 96166L, 
    96166L, 96166L, 2395L, 2395L, 2395L, 2395L, 2395L, 2890L, 
    2890L, 2890L, 2890L, 2890L, 2891L, 2891L, 2891L, 2891L, 2891L, 
    75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 5346L, 5346L, 5346L, 5346L, 5346L, 
    600L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 65020L, 65020L, 65020L, 65020L, 65020L, 
    1261L, 1261L, 1261L, 1261L, 668L, 668L, 668L, 668L, 668L, 
    1425L, 1425L, 1425L, 1425L, 1425L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 
    900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 
    900L, 900L, 900L, 900L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 362L, 40258L, 40258L, 
    40258L, 40258L, 40268L, 40268L, 40268L, 40268L, 2549L, 2549L, 
    2549L, 2549L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 
    96L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 132L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -710L))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the most general case, you expect something to happen X times in a given timeframe if it, well, happened X times in a comparable timeframe in the past.

```
output <- aggregate(df$PANID, by = list(df$ITEM, df$PANID), length)
colnames(output) <- c('ITEM', 'PANID', 'COUNT')
k <- as.integer(max(df$WEEK) - min(df$WEEK)) / 7 # number of weeks in the data
output$EXPECTATION <- output$COUNT / k
head(output)

#ITEM   PANID COUNT EXPECTATION
#1  106 3104497     5   0.4166667
#2  240 3104497     5   0.4166667
#3  526 3104497     5   0.4166667
#4  548 3104497     5   0.4166667
#5  900 3104497     5   0.4166667
#6 1251 3104497     5   0.4166667
```

That said, it's a very back-of-the-envelope calculation. With more data (e.g. with longer timeframes and greater temporal resolution), you could look into seasonality (it's not very reasonable to expect the sales to remain constant from month to month, right). If you had actual features describing `PANID`s and `ITEM`s, you could look into possible relationships between those features and purchase counts. Really, there's hardly a limit to how sophisticated one could get with such analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes I have more time frame data, I am looking into seasonality of the data also (I know there exists some for some products, such as beer etc. - think Christmas, superbowl, 4th July - all spikes). I have data on `PANID`'s such as how many cats, dogs,TV's, sex, age, race etc. (Its a rich dataset). I also have product information also. I was just looking for a begining point. My plan was to apply a Naive Bayes and then get a little more complicated with NN or which ever ML method would be suitable.

Comment: If you have more data, you can totally try building a model of sorts. Those are very vast topics though! Look into forecasting with ARIMA models, this may help with the seasonality. And by all means this problem sounds like one amenable to ML; there's tons of relevant tutorials online. And if you get stuck, post a specific request for help!

Comment: At this stage I just wanted to get a `Y` variable because at the moment I have this rich panel level dataset but do not know exactly how to find an outcome variable for it. I think its super interesting to find out which `PANELID`s / People are more likely to buy certain products based on past purchases but I just could not think of a way to find this `Y` variable... if this makes sense.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense to define the outcome variable as precisely the thing that you are trying to find out: probability of purchase (y) given customer profile and item (x)